# Login doesn't work and says NoReverseMatch at /basic_app/user_login/ but registration seems to work fine with similar url pattern and template tagging

Tags: django

I couldn't find the solution to this problem, not even in Stack Overflow. Same question was asked but I could not find a definite answer.
Code in views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basic_app.forms import UserForm, UserProfileInfoForm

# For Login
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username') 
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username='username', password='password')

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

            else:
                HttpResponse("ACCOUNT IS NOT ACTIVE! PLEASE REGISTER FIRST!")
        
        else:
            print('Someone tried to login $ failed!')
            print('Username: {} and Password: {}'.format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse('INVALID USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD')
    else:
        return render(request, 'basic_app/login.html', {})
```

And the code in base.html with link to get to login page:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'user_logout' %}" >Logout</a>
  </li>
{% else %}
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'basic_app:user_login' %}" >Login</a>
  </li>
{% endif %}
```

This is the code in urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from basic_app import views

```
app_name = 'basic_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('user_login/', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
]
```

Comment: Can you post a complete traceback?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this but I could not add more than 600 words so please consider looking at this for traceback:
https://www.zippyjot.com/note/42400

Comment: Did you try: `<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'user_login' %}" >Login</a>`

Comment: Based on your suggestion I changed the URL patterns not only in base.html but also index.html and urls.py in base directory and it worked but the problem is that it is no longer modular. I cannot still use urls.py in my app's folder to do the same task.
If you have suggestion for that please help.
And thank you for this suggestion as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I found a way to make this work but it will no longer be modular

STEP 1) Change the url template tagging to `"{% url 'your_view' %}"` in all the places where you had `"{% url 'your_app:your_view' %}"`

---

STEP 2) Add this line in urlpatterns under base directory's url.py file(**NOTE: NOT IN YOUR APP'S urls.py file**)

```
path('url_pattern/', views.your_view, name='your_view'),
```